# Prove or disprove: for any two given functions, one must be upper bounding the other

Tags: real-analysis

$f \in O(g)$ definition:$$ \exists c \in \mathbb{R^+}, \exists B \in \mathbb{N}, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, n \geq B \Rightarrow f(n) \leq cg(n) $$

$f \in \Omega(g)$ definition:: $$ \exists c \in \mathbb{R^+}, \exists B \in \mathbb{N}, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, n \geq B \Rightarrow f(n) \geq cg(n) $$

Here is the question:

Given the set of functions $F = {f: \mathbb{N} \to\mathbb{R^{\geq0}}}$, prove or disprove:

$$\forall f, g \in F, f\in O(g) \lor f \in \Omega(g).$$

I couldn't even determine whether the statement is true or false. Not sure if $f=|\cos x|$ and $g=|\sin x|$ an counterexample to the statement?

here is part that confuse me: I need to disprove the statement by first prove $f \notin O(g)$, then I need to prove the negation of $ \exists c \in \mathbb{R^+}, \exists B \in \mathbb{N}, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, n \geq B \Rightarrow f(n) \leq cg(n) $, but since two functions interwine, i don't know how prove the negation of big-O {$\forall c \in \mathbb{R^+}, \forall B\in \mathbb{N}, \exists \mathbb{N}, n \geq B \land (f(n)>cg(n)) $}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right general idea for a counterexample, but it would be better to replace $x$ by $n\pi$: then you can more easily calculate the values and see that they intertwine as $n$ increases.

An easier example: $f(n)=(-1)^n+1$, and $g(n)=(-1)^{n+1}+1$.

Comment: using your example to prove the negation of Big-O, I prove  {$\forall c \in \mathbb{R^+}, \forall B\in \mathbb{N}, \exists \mathbb{N}, n \geq B \land (f(n)>cg(n)) $}. I need $n$ to be even and bigger than B, so I choose $n$ = max$(2B,2\left \lceil{c}\right \rceil)$ . does it work?

Comment: @Hobbit6094: Why not just notice that $f(n)=2$ and $g(n)=0$ when $n$ is even, so no matter what $c$ you pick, $f(n)\not\le cg(n)$ when $n$ is even. And you can find even numbers as big as you want: just take $n=2B$, for instance.

Comment: lol, I'm so stupide......thx so much

Comment: @Hobbit6094: You’re welcome! (Not stupid: just working a little too hard. That’s pretty common when you’re just starting.)

Answer (score 0):

Compare:
$$ y = e^x$$
and 
$$ y = e^x + \sin(x)$$

Comment: Well, I compared these $f$ and $g$ and I found that $f\in\Theta(g)$. How is this a counterexample to the assertion that for every $f$ and $g$, either $f\in O(g)$ or $f\in\Omega(g)$?